# using dedicated IP of VPS for your personal web server

Tags: networking, server, vps, dedicated-server, dedicated-hosting

**Pretext:** There is a ABC company providing Virtual Private Server for $xx, which includes features like blah1, blah2, blah3 and **1 dedicated IP address**.

I have my home FiOS internet connection.
I have serverA, serverB, serverC running at my home.

Let's assume ServerA is a web server.

**Scenario 1:**
To access this web serve from outside my LAN, I would type "myDynamicIPAddress", we are assuming it still has the same lease token, and get access to my website successfully.

**Scenario 2:**
I am at my school/work(I work at a corporate office). I would type "myDynamicIPAddress" to access my web server. Since my IP address is dynamic/residential, it is blocked(All residential IP are blocked by default, to reduce the chance of them getting infected and sending out spams).

**My question:**
Is there any way to connect my home network to the VPS that I purchased(the one with dedicated IP, remember?), so that I can use that dedicated IP address to connect to my web server from my school/work where residential IP address are blocked(this also means no Dyndns.com/no-ip.com).

I hope I explained my question correctly and I posted it in the right section.

Thank You in advance.

EDIT1: I found this one question, but I want to do the exact opposite of what the user in this question is asking for.
https://superuser.com/questions/498529/is-it-possible-to-use-a-static-ip-assigned-by-my-isp-for-an-offsite-web-server-o

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same as the other question, for the same reasons. The IP address is routed to the owning network prefix so it can't be used at a different location without changing the Internet routing tables to point the overall prefix to route to a different place. Since you don't own the network prefix, you can't do that.

Comment: I was thinking of something a little different. What if the VPS was a VPN server and I make my web server connect to VPN. Then hypothetically, if you typed in my VPS's IP address, you should be able to see the web server.This sound all good and all in my head, but is that not correct?